# Override a complicated class with multiple parameters

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to override the class `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener`.

```
parameters:
    security.authentication.listener.form.class: AppBundle\Listener\LoginFormListener

class LoginFormListener extends UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener
{
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager, SessionAuthenticationStrategyInterface $sessionStrategy, HttpUtils $httpUtils, $providerKey, AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface $successHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface $failureHandler, array $options = array(), LoggerInterface $logger = null, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher = null, CsrfProviderInterface $csrfProvider = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($securityContext, $authenticationManager, $sessionStrategy, $httpUtils, $providerKey, $successHandler, $failureHandler, $options, $logger, $dispatcher, $csrfProvider);
    }

    protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
    {

        if (null !== $this->csrfTokenManager) {
            $csrfToken = $request->get($this->options['csrf_parameter'], null, true);

            if (false === $this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid(new CsrfToken($this->options['intention'], $csrfToken))) {
                throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException('Invalid CSRF token.');
            }
        }

        if ($this->options['post_only']) {
            $username = trim($request->request->get($this->options['username_parameter'], null, true));
            $password = $request->request->get($this->options['password_parameter'], null, true);
        } else {
            $username = trim($request->get($this->options['username_parameter'], null, true));
            $password = $request->get($this->options['password_parameter'], null, true);
        }

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $username);

        $apiRequest = new ApiRequest();
        $apiRequest->addMethod('login', array('email' => $username, 'password' => $password));
        $response = $apiRequest->sendRequest();
        dump($response);
        exit;
    }
}
```

But when I execute it, I have this error :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Listener\LoginFormListener::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage given, called in /Users/dimitri/Sites/rennes/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 4039 and defined
```

Any idea how I can make this work ?

Comment: According to the definition of the class you want to override, it accepts an instance of `TokenStorageInterface`, but in your class, the first argument is an instance of `SecurityContextInterface`. Check out the original code [here](https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/master/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php) and modify your class accordingly.

Comment: You are right, I have no idea how I could missed it? But I just changed it and it does the same error. I have already cleared the cache... EDIT: I just forgot to use the class, works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change `SecurityContextInterface` type hint to `TokenStorageInterface` in your class and all should work fine - this class service has been changed recently (deprecated in 2.7) , so your example code might be outdated.

Check [blog post entry](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements) to get more info about 
`SecurityContextInterface` vs `TokenStorageInterface`